# Como leer un archivo y guardar los datos en un array en C

Tags: c

Hola buenas necesito ayuda debido a que haciendo un proyect para la universidad tengo bastantes problemas para poder abrir un archivo leerlo y guardar los datos en un array utilizando getline(), ademas tengo una libreria creada que mi programa pincipal no ve alguien podria yudarme porfavor, muchas gracias.

```
            byte = getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            token = strtok(aux, s);
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            strcpy(cell[cont].id, token);
```

Comment: ¿Qué contiene el archivo? ¿Cómo está organizado el archivo? ¿cómo es el array en que quieres guardar los datos?

Comment: y qué problema estás teniendo exactamente? Piensa que esas líneas que has puesto, por si solas, no suponen un problema

Comment: el arcivo contiene unas celdas donde se ha almacenado informacion de un wifi y yo quiero que mi programa lo abra y lo guarde en un array que se pasa por parametro con un struct hecho con la informacion de cada parametro es decir el id, el essid, el modo, frecuencia, etc. despues de poner estas lineas me da un error de buffer